# How to find correct pixels in imagine?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to find every 80th pixel in every 80th row of the .bmp image. Can somebody suggest me how to make it correct. I did it, but not sure that it's correct, because in my quize said that an image contains a message "In those pixels, the numeric value for a character was added to 100 to set the blue value." (in this case my method isn't working)

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("UIC.bmp")
print(im.size) #it gives: (1200, 800)
x = 80
y = 80
blue_list = []
for i in range(0,9):
    pix = im.load()
    blue_list.append(list(pix[x,y])[2])
    print (list(pix[x,y]))
    x += 80
    y += 80


print(blue_list) #gives list with blue value of every 80th pixel[211, 211, 203, 148, 214, 212, 132, 132, 132]
```

Comment: Note that x,y are reversed everywhere here

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what do you mean, can you please explain it, or send a link with information about it. I'm new to this theme, so for me hard to understand some things

Comment: Indexing in arrays is [row,column].You use x,y which can confuse you since x is usually used as a column index and y is the row index. It doesn't really matter here because you are consistent and you use 80 for both.

Comment: oh, I get it, thanks. So the code is running correctly?

Comment: No, you are looking only on pixels in indices [80*i,80*i], where according to you problem description you want indices [80*i, 80*j]. Meaning, the column index and the row index should be independent, to look for every 80th pixel in every 80th row. You need two loops...

Comment: like this?

'for i in range(0,1200, 80):
    pix = im.load()
    pix_list.append(list(pix[x,y])[2])
    print (list(pix[x,y]))
    print(pix[x, y])
    y += 80
    for j in range(0, 800, 80):
        pix = im.load()
        pix_list.append(list(pix[x, y]))
        print(pix[x, y])
        x += 80'